# read and write only a line not the full file

Tags: python, file

i have the following problem in the code below.

I open a file and load it into "csproperties" (Comment #open path). In every open file i want to make three changes (Comment #change parameters). Then i want to write the three changes to the file and close it. I want to do this file per file.

When i now open the changed file, the file has three times the same content. In content one i can see my first change, in content two the second and so on.

I do not understand why my tool writes the full file content 3 times in an changed file.

i think it hat somethink to do with the #write file Block... i tried serverell things, but nothing worked the right way.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards

```
for instance in cs_id:
    cspath.append(cs_id[n] + '/mypath/conf/myfile.txt')

    # open path
    f = open(cspath[n], "r")
    csproperties = f.read()
    f.close()

    #change parameters
    CS_License_Key_New = csproperties.replace(oms + "CSLicenseKey=", oms + "CSLicenseKey="+ keystore[n])
    Logfile_New = csproperties.replace(oms + "LogFile=", oms + "LogFile=" + logs + 'ContentServer_' + cs_id[n] +'.log')
    Pse_New = csproperties.replace(oms + "PABName=", oms + "PABName=" + pse + 'ContentServer_' + cs_id[n] + '.PSE')

    #write File
    f = open(cspath[n],'w')
    f.write(CS_License_Key_New)
    f.write(Logfile_New)
    f.write(Pse_New)
    f.close()

    n += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing 3 different replaces on the same content. You should chain the replaces instead:

```
result = (csproperties
          .replace(oms + "CSLicenseKey=", oms + "CSLicenseKey="+ keystore[n])
          .replace(oms + "LogFile=", 
                   oms + "LogFile=" + logs + 'ContentServer_' + cs_id[n] +'.log')
          .replace(oms + "PABName=",
                   oms + "PABName=" + pse + 'ContentServer_' + cs_id[n] + '.PSE'))
...
f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CS_License_Key_New = csproperties.replace(...)
Logfile_New = csproperties.replace(...)
Pse_New = csproperties.replace(...)
```

There are three different copies of content.

You are trying to replace content and save it to three different variables.

You should do it in once time.